# UITableView reload animation doesn't work properly

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, uiviewanimation

I have a table view which reloads it data with animation on button tap. It was working great until there was one label with text. 
I use this code to reload data with animation for one button (I have only one section):

```
 tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integersIn: 0..<tableView.numberOfSections), with: UITableViewRowAnimation.right)
```

and this for another button:

```
 tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integersIn: 0..<tableView.numberOfSections), with: UITableViewRowAnimation.left)
```

And on the top of table view it works okay, but in the middle or in the end it scrolling. 
Link for gif - https://giphy.com/gifs/l0DAHUyzm7BMGnKrm/html5

Then I added this code for reloading with animation:

```
        let offset = tableView.contentOffset 
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integersIn: 0..<tableView.numberOfSections), with: UITableViewRowAnimation.left)
        tableView.endUpdates()
        tableView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        tableView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: false)
```

Same code for .right animation. It fixed scrolling, but added another issue. Again on top of table view it works okay, but then... Watch gif please.
Link for gif - https://giphy.com/gifs/xT1R9Gfaa2po6dMf2U/html5

I'm using test data to fill table view, not fetching or something else.
Hope for help, thanks

EDIT: 
I found that if I set standard cell height from code animation works nice, only in this case it works:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 44.0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The problem was in cell height, animation was starting for estimated cell height in 44.0 and my cell height is 117.0. So this code fixed my problem:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 117.0
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 117.0
}
```